# Save on Notes Code Error

Tags: ios, swift3

I am using this code to create a notes app, from a tutorial. I got stuck in saving the data as the code is showing some errors.[List of Errors on the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTf3T.png)

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        objects.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}

func save(){
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(objects, value(forKey: kNotes)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
func load(){
    if let loadedData = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: kNotes) as? [String]{
    objects = loadedData
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: The tutorial that you are following is slightly older than the version of Swift that you are using. Don't worry, since this is not a big deal, but some of the methods that you are calling have changed, such as ``standardUserDefaults()`` is now ``standard``, just like S1lent Warrior points out in his answer. Also be careful with missing parenthesis ``()`` :)

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving these errors because your syntax in not the valid swift 3 syntax.

You're also missing a closing bracket in the first line of your method `save`.

so he is how you `save` method should look like in swift 3:

```
func save() {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(objects, forKey: kNotes)
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```

Hope this helps